# Mismatch in generic parameter inference between TypeScript 3.5 and 3.6

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to understand the typechecking of following code:

```
const marker = Symbol();

type ConstItem = string | number | null;
type Item = ConstItem | { [index: string]: string };
type WrapOrConst<T extends Item> = Wrap<T> | (T extends ConstItem ? T : never);
type Wrap<T extends Item> = {
    __marker: typeof marker,
    __phantom: T;
}

declare function wrapped<T extends Item>(item: T): Wrap<T>;
declare function str(): string;

type UnionInner<T extends Array<WrapOrConst<Item>>> = T extends Array<WrapOrConst<infer U>> ? U : never;
declare function Union<T extends WrapOrConst<Item>[]>(...inner: T): Wrap<UnionInner<T>>;

const test = Union(wrapped(str()), null);
const test2: string | null = test.__phantom;
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.6.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwE4GsCmSYF4YGUCecARiADYAUAlANwCwAUA1PgA5owDC40AklGnGwxoSAJZgA5jAA%20MMAFdiGGXPmlSdeszYw%20AoV0hQ9g2QG8YAbXEATNAA8AXMKhjJAXWcjxUgL6btdgB1JAQWAHkkQ2gAHgAVGAd%20MBsIXX44AD4hELD47NlyBKS0FLTo4wyYAH4YBOcwNAA3DBomVmDQlnjE%202TU9IFsnDMGGHGYAH1JxFQMZ0CQADN4ZHQkABoxiemWAAsEMCgQOGc4zV8GBjtgUmR2JfkwYChRcBgAdy62Gx6SssGWXIogyZ0ozly3TimU0NzuSAeTxebzALiQVC8rh8mnaOgAqmAUTwwI0kH8%20qUBgBBJChfAxSGRCoxEyZNlCYoUgE0ukMrpM7hQGLiJbKPHs2p4mANZoYWFoW73GCPZ6vd4ElHk-ppRlRQUsjKZSzuTLkAB0FvEpLBEK6MQ14GJpPyMKu9FARhg-GgQgdYHIXzCP3IIiolA2qnUbXdgq9aGgACZMW4pLIFOohN6oGbdgcjidqEA)

This works fine in the TypeScript 3.6, but fails in TypeScript 3.5, since `test` is inferred to be `Wrap<Item>` and not `Wrap<string | null>`. I wasn't able to find something in the release notes; was it simply a bug? Can I somehow work around this issue in earlier versions (ideally, down to TypeScript 3.1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it was considered a bug ([microsoft/TypeScript#32434](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32434)) whereby generic type parameter inference involving certain unions produced undesirable results.  It was [fixed (microsoft/TypeScript#32460)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32460) for TypeScript 3.6, as you've noticed.

To get your code to work in previous versions you probably have to refactor to involve fewer explicit unions in your inference sites, like this:

```
type Unwrap<U extends Item | Wrap<Item>> = U extends Wrap<infer I> ? I : U
declare function Union<T extends WrapOrConst<Item>[]>(...inner: T): Wrap<Unwrap<T[number]>>;
```

That seems to behave the way you want:

```
const test = Union(wrapped(str()), null).__phantom; // string | null
```

But of course I don't know the full set of use cases you have, so there are probably edge cases where the desired behavior differs from what the above gives you.  But this should hopefully give you an idea on how to proceed.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwE4GsCmSYF4YGUCecARiADYAUAlANwCwAUA1PgA5owDC40AklGnGwxoSAJZgA5jAA+MMAFdiGGXPmlSdeszYw+AoV0hQ9g2QG8YAbXEATNAA8AXMKhjJAXWcjxUgL6btdgB1JAQWAHkkQ2gAHgAVGAd+MBsIXX44AD4hELD47NlyBKS0FLTo4wyYAH4YBOcwNAA3DBomVmDQlnjE+2TU9IFsnDMGGHGYAH1JxFQMZ0CQADN4ZHQkABoxiemWAAsEMCgQOGc46hgGXwYGO2BSZHYl+TBgKFFwGAB3LrYbHpKZUGWXIogyZ0ozly3TimU0dweSCeLzeHzALiQVC8rh8AQ6MAAqmAfnkCb1+mkTCpoTETJlhoTyaUBjTxEtlDxsrUeDBnATbmh7o8YM9Xu9PkS0QC+sy0tDIhVaRlMpZ3JlyAA6LXiRpICFQroxIkkmGWBRKJBquE3eigIwwfjQISS8DkE1-cgiKiUDaqdSUDW7A5HE4XAD0YYxPhUCnUDCAA)

Comment: I'm yet to test this on real code, but playground seems to work all the way down to 3.0, thanks!